# How to get property values by name

Tags: delphi, properties, devexpress, styling

I have a class with some published properties that I want to list.
The properties are of type TcxCustomStyle which are from DevExpress styling.
I use the following code to add the names to a memdata table and if I remove all the TcxCustomStyle related it works OK.

The question is how do I get the value of a property that is of type TcxCustomStyle?

Most likely it is simple error by my side - but I can't figure out what.

```
procedure TfrmMain.ListProperties;
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  rType: TRttiType;
  rProp: TRttiProperty;
  i: integer;
  Value: TcxCustomStyle;
begin
  i := 1;
  memProperties.DisableControls;
  try
    memProperties.Close;
    memProperties.Open;

    rType := ctx.GetType(Settings.Styling.ClassType);
    for rProp in rType.GetProperties do
      begin
        Value := TcxCustomStyle(rProp.GetValue(Self).AsObject);
        memProperties.AppendRecord([i, rProp.Name, Value.Name]);
        Inc(i);
      end;

  finally
    ctx.Free;
    memProperties.EnableControls;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You don't need the call to `ctx.Free` and can simply remove it since it serves no purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell for sure what is wrong, because we are missing a lot of the details. Not least the fact that you included none of the information about the types, and no error message.

The thing that leaps out at me is that you set `rType` to be the type specified by `Settings.Styling.ClassType`. Then you iterate across its properties and read them from an instance `Self` that is of type `TfrmMain`. That looks wrong. The parameter that you pass to `GetValue` must be of type `Settings.Styling.ClassType`. I expect that you need to pass a different instance to `GetValue`.

I'd also question the use of an unchecked cast `TcxCustomStyle(...)`. That just makes like hard for you. Use a checked cast: `... as TcxCustomStyle`.

Your code also assumes that all properties of `Settings.Styling.ClassType` are of type `TcxCustomStyle`. Perhaps that's a reasonable assumption, I don't know.

Comment: The error is: Invalid class typecast

All the properties are of type TcxCustomStyle - it is a style used to set color/font and many other things used in DevExpress controls.

Comment: That error is presumably in rProp.GetValue(Self) because, as I said, you pass an instance that is not of the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time looking in old code I rewrote the function to the following working code.
Now I have only to figure out how to store a description of each property in the class also - I have seen that done.  I need both the TcxCustomStyle value and a description I can display.  But that is a whole other question.

```
procedure TfrmMain.ListProperties;
var
  ctx       : TRttiContext;
  lType     : TRttiType;
  lProperty : TRttiProperty;
  i         : integer;
  Value     : TcxCustomStyle;
begin
  i := 1;
  memProperties.DisableControls;
  ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  try
    memProperties.Close;
    memProperties.Open;

    lType := ctx.GetType(Settings.Styling.ClassType);
    for lProperty in lType.GetProperties do
      begin
        Value := TcxCustomStyle(lProperty.GetValue(Settings.Styling).AsObject);
        memProperties.AppendRecord([i, lProperty.Name, Value.Name]);
        Inc(i);
      end;

  finally
    ctx.Free;
    memProperties.EnableControls;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I don't understand why you added this answer that simply follows the advice that I gave you. And doesn't follow the sound advice about checked casts. And there's really no point at all in calling `ctx := TRttiContext.Create` and `ctx.Free`. Those lines can be removed.

Comment: I didn't use the as TcxCustomStyle cast because I get an AV
And the answer was added just to show what I ended up with that is working.

The ctx not being removed is my mistake - sorry. It is done in the final code

Comment: If the checked `as` cast doesn't work, then the unchecked cast won't work either, but you may not get an error message right away. That's the advantage of the checked cast - you find out immediately if you made a mistake.

Comment: I figured out that the AV wasn't caused by the typecast after all and now it works as per your suggestion. I can load and save propertyvalues to and from my db and change my styling according to that.   -  thank you for your input.  Now I will go on to next issue = storing extra info with a property.